# Toggle variables in other classes without setters/getters

Tags: java, class, object, oop

I currently have an object called `UserSettings` containing a number of variables of user preferences.

In another class called `playerLabels`, I instantiate the object like this:
`public static UserSettings settings = new UserSettings();`

In a third class, I read from a file and edit the settings object by doing (e.g) `playerLabels.settings.setToggled(true);`

I have a number of boolean values in the settings file, some of which I want to toggle (switch on->off or off->on).
From how I see it, there are three ways to do this:

1. `playerLabels.settings.toggled = !playerLabels.settings.toggled;`
2. `playerLabels.settings.setToggled(!playerLabels.settings.getToggled());`
3. create a toggle method in `settings` for each boolean value

I learned to use setters and getters with java instead of directly accessing the variable which is why I don't want to do the first.

The second is a bit long and feels clumsy however if that's the way to do it that's fine.

The third would be time consuming to create methods for each boolean value.

I have a feeling that my method of storing user preferences isn't ideal, as I'm accessing another unneccessary class (playerLabels) to edit settings. If there is a better way to store variables in the way I want to, that would be helpful.

Thanks

UserSettings:

```
public class UserSettings {
    private boolean toggled = true;
    private float height = 0f;
    private boolean shadow = true;
    private boolean personal = false;

    public boolean isToggled() {
        return toggled;
    }

    public void setToggled(boolean toggled) {
        this.toggled = toggled;
    }

    public float getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(float height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public boolean isShadow() {
        return shadow;
    }

    public void setShadow(boolean shadow) {
        this.shadow = shadow;
    }

    public boolean isPersonal() {
        return personal;
    }

    public void setPersonal(boolean personal) {
        this.personal = personal;
    }

}
```

Comment: actually getter and setters are more ideal than playerLabels.settings.toggled = !playerLabels.settings.toggled;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short you can't without writing a method within the class that holds the private variables.  The whole point of creating private variables is to limit the access and thus encapsulate the variables.  If you want to toggle it, write a method that uses the getters/settings to toggle it.

Comment: That makes sense thankyou, could I store the variables in a class without having to go through playerLabels.settings or is the way I'm doing it right now better.

Comment: Think of the class you are writing as an physical object.  If the attribute belongs on the object, it should be directly set on the object and you should use methods to alter it.  If you are using a method called settings to set the object  initially, that works fine.  You might also consider writing a constructor that sets the variables when the object is set.  Just pass in the values you want set into the constructor, then call the setters within the constructor code.

Comment: That is very helpful thankyou, and the reason I didn't use a constructor was because when I instantiate it in playerLables, it doesn't have any of the attributes at that point. These are taken from a file in another class and set there.
Maybe I should instaniate the class in the class where I read the values from the file

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be lazy and not add a toggle() method for each setting, you can create a new class:

```
public class ToggleOption {

    private boolean value;
    
    public ToggleOption() {}

    public ToggleOption(boolean initialValue) {
        this.value = initialValue;
    }
    
    get() {
        return value;
    }

    set(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    toggle() {
        this.value = !value;
    }
}
```

In your UserSettings class you then use this new class instead of the boolean flags:

```
public class UserSettings {
    private ToggleOption toggled = new ToggleOption(true);
    private float height = 0f;
    private ToggleOption shadow = new ToggleOption(true);
    private ToggleOption personal = new ToggleOption();

    ...
}
```

To toggle, you simply call

```
playerLabels.settings.getToggled().toggle();
```

Comment: "simply call" ... you want to read about the "Law of Demeter" in programming. Sure, the above works, but it is an anti-pattern that you absolutely avoid in real world code.

Comment: That looks good, however I'm now considering using an empty class and storing all user settings as `public static` types at the top. Is that a bad idea?

Comment: @GhostCat add an interface layer with toggle() declaration then

Comment: @VosemMedia Yep. `static` is like the opposite of good OO. It gives you hard coupling between classes, it doesn't work with polymorphism and inheritance either. In other words: static should be the rare exception in your java code ...

Comment: Oh okay I understand, I'll stick with the current way then. Thanks